# Mongodb: check value equality in any document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a form on my site where users can enter a number into the `subNum` field. When the user submits the form, I want to check if the value they've entered already exists as a value in any existing document. This is all done in javascript/meteor

All form data gets put into an object like this:

```
participantObject = {
  subNum: parseInt(number)
}
```

This object then gets inserted as a document into the `Participants` collection

When the submit button is clicked, I need to check whether the number they've entered has already been entered (i.e. exists as the value for `subNum` in any document). If so, prevent form submit and show an error

I'm trying the check with something like this:

```
var existingSubs = Participants.find(
  {subNum: {$eq: participantObject.subNum}}
).count();

console.log(existingSubs);
```

I am hoping that the above will find me all documents where `subNum` is equal to the value entered (`participantObject.subNum`), and console log the count of the number of matching documents

The problem is that in the console log I see `Unrecognized operator: $eq`

Am I using the equality operator incorrectly?

Is there a more efficient way to perform a check like this?

Comment: This seems to be a open [`issue`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4142).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [omit `$eq` operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#equals-a-specified-value):

```
var existingSubs = Participants.find(
    {subNum: participantObject.subNum}
).count();
```